# Is there a similar function to ctrl+d in VScode in netbeans or eclipse that can change multiple lines at a time?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, visual-studio-code

I just wanted to know if netbeans or eclipse has a similar function to vscode that can allow multiple lines to be changed at a time (Ctrl+d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans supports [multicarets](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB82#Editor_Multicarets). Just use CTRL+ALT+Click to place another caret.